# Grid OnDataItemBound Event

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, webforms

What should go inside this method?  I have a grid displaying results from my SQL Query --- but the grid never populates.  The grid is created using HTML and this is how my OnDataItemBound event reads....but what should go here?

```
protected void dtgfourfiveseven_OnItemDataBound(object sender, DataGridItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
  {                                                   

  }
}
```

This is my html I am using to create the grid

```
<asp:DataGrid runat="server" ID="dtgfourfiveseven" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="DataGrids"
GridLines="Both" ShowFooter="true" Visible="false" OnItemDataBound="dtgfourfiveseven_OnItemDataBound">
<ItemStyle CssClass="row" />
<FooterStyle CssClass="DataGridFooters" />
<HeaderStyle CssClass="DataGridHeaders" />
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Employee Name" HeaderText="Employee Name" ItemStyle-Width="100px"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Eligible For Rehire" HeaderText="Eligible For Rehire" ItemStyle-Width="50px"></asp:BoundColumn>
    <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Not Eligible For Rehire" HeaderText="Not Eligible For Rehire" ItemStyle-Width="50px"></asp:BoundColumn>
</Columns>
```

Comment: What does the grid code in your .aspx file look like?

Comment: @ekad is that what you were needing to see?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the OnDataItemBound event is not what is preventing the data from displaying.  Either your query is returning 0 rows, or you are not binding the query results to the grid.  Per MSDN this is what you use the OnDataItemBound event for:

> Use the ItemDataBound event to customize the DataGrid control. The ItemDataBound event allows you to access the data before the item is displayed in the control.

An common example of this would be manipulating the data that is returned from your query.  I.E. formatting a column to currency.

Thank you for providing the code on how you actually generate your grid through html, but please also provide additional code.  Showing how you are actually executing your SQL Query, and how you are actually binding the query results to the grid will allow us to further assist in troubleshooting what is the culprit here.

EDIT ---
A second thought that comes to mind, that may be a quick thing to check is, are you setting the `grid.visible = false` and not setting it to true later on so the grid is showing your data it is just not showing on the page?